# How do I search historic mercurial file content?

Tags: search, mercurial, tortoisehg

I've found an issue in my code where something used to be specified, but is no longer, so I want to search for a particular string through the history of the repository.

Is there a way to do this in TortoiseHg? *I know it would take a while, but it'd take me longer...*

Comment: Nope, it doesn't take a while. Well, about 30 seconds for 1000 revisions.

Comment: ... and then if you did it again it would probably be faster due to having a warm cache.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Menu "View" -> "Search". This will open the search pane which you can use to search for strings inside your

- working copy, all history, specific revision
- with inclusion file patterns
- and exclusion file patterns

Answer (score 42):

If you don't mind working with Mercurial via the command line, there's `hg grep`. It's probably exposed somewhere in the TortoiseHg Workbench, but I don't know.

Comment: Wow! That was awesome! Much faster than our fisheye server (on svn); and it's specific to my repository!

Comment: Yep, the way hg stores it all locally helps to make such things fast and helpful.

Comment: TortoiseHg Workbench: The second icon from right is "Search" and the 6th icon from the left is "Filter Graph" (this shows up as "Filter Toolbar" in the pulldown menus). You probably want the "Search" function.

Comment: To search a specific file: hg grep 'somestring' -l "fileA.js"